# XSLT renaming a file

Tags: xslt

I have a xml as result of a xslt transformation (version 1.0). The problem is that this result xml could be empty. When this file is empty I should rename the file (to dummy.xml) from xslt code NOT from my project. Anyone know a solution? Thanks

Comment: I don't get it: Your transformation has a result xml which is to be renamed? How does it get it's original name? XSLT 1.0 can't name this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You can't do that. Sorry.

Whatever environment is hosting your XSLT will have to do it.

Comment: So there is no way to rename the file if the xml output is empty? even if I change to version 2.0?

Comment: If you use XSLT 2.0 then you could use the `xsl:result-document` statement. However, the primary output is still not defined from within the XSLT itself

Comment: I use 1.0 but in any case if I would use 2.0, I should change the name only in some circunstances so I guess there is no solution in XSLT. Thanks.